# How do I align my text vertically within a table cell?

Tags: html, css, vertical-text

I've been scouring the web for hours now on many different forums, but no one seems to have the answers I need. How do I align my text vertically in a table cell? Like that: But without spaces

V

E

R

T

I

C

A

L

Here is my code:

```css
.VerticalText {
    -ms-writing-mode: tb-lr;
    -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    -moz-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    }
```

```html
<table width="98%" border="1" style="">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <table width="98%" border="1" style="">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2">TEXT</td>
          <td rowspan="2">TEXT</td>
          <td colspan="7" align="center">TEXT</td>
          <td rowspan="2">TEXT</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="VerticalText">TEXT</td>
          <td>VERTICAL TEXT</td>
          <td>VERTICAL TEXT</td>
          <td>VERTICAL TEXT</td>
          <td>VERTICAL TEXT</td>
          <td>VERTICAL TEXT</td>
          <td>VERTICAL TEXT</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I have tried text orientation, textdirection, etc.

I'm lost, can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the text in a `span`, make that a block element and give it a very small `width` (so that only one letter fits in there) and also `word-break: break-all;`, so the words actually break into single letters. (I assigned the changed `.VerticalText` class to the `span` elements in my example below)

```css
.VerticalText {
  display: block;
  width: 0.9em;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<table width="98%" border="1" style="">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <table width="98%" border="1" style="">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">TEXT</td>
            <td rowspan="2">TEXT</td>
            <td colspan="7" align="center">TEXT</td>
            <td rowspan="2">TEXT</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>TEXT</td>
            <td><span class="VerticalText">VERTICAL TEXT</span></td>
            <td><span class="VerticalText">VERTICAL TEXT</span></td>
            <td><span class="VerticalText">VERTICAL TEXT</span></td>
            <td><span class="VerticalText">VERTICAL TEXT</span></td>
            <td><span class="VerticalText">VERTICAL TEXT</span></td>
            <td><span class="VerticalText">VERTICAL TEXT</span></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```